# VLC rename current item with lua script

Tags: windows, lua, vlc

I am using this script as a template to rename a file in VLC: https://github.com/surrim/vlc-delete/
The Script works as intended.

My code looks like this:

```
function descriptor()
    return {
        title = "VLC Rename";
        version = "0.1";
        author = "I";
        shortdesc = "Rename current file";
        description = [[
<h1>vlc-rename</h1>"
When you're playing a file, use VLC Rename
to rename the current file]];
    }
end

function removeItem()
    local id = vlc.playlist.current()
    vlc.playlist.delete(id)
    vlc.playlist.gotoitem(id + 1)
    vlc.deactivate()
end

function activate()
    local item = vlc.input.item()
    local uri = item:uri()
    oldFile = vlc.strings.decode_uri(string.gsub(uri, "^file:///", ""))

    d = vlc.dialog( "Rename Dialog" )
    d:add_label("Filename")
    w = d:add_text_input(oldFile, 1, 5,200 ,30)
    d:add_button("OK", click_ok)
    d:show()

end

function click_ok()
    local newFile = w:get_text()
    vlc.msg.info("[vlc-rename] renaming: " .. oldFile .. " with " .. newFile)
    if newFile ~=  oldFile then
        removeItem()
        retval, err = os.rename(oldFile,newFile)
        vlc.msg.info("[vlc-rename] end rename")

        if (retval == nil) then
            vlc.msg.err("[vlc-rename]  fail: " .. err)
        end
    end
    d:delete()
    vlc.deactivate()
end

function deactivate()
    vlc.deactivate()
end

function close()
    deactivate()
end

function meta_changed()
end
```

This code outputs an error from the os.rename() function:
lua error: [vlc-rename] fail: [my filename] Permission denied
Regardless of elevation level.

I am using windows 10 64bit and VLC 3.03.
Since this is my first lua script I welcome any input.

Comment: Perhaps try os.execute("ren " .. <your old file> .. " " <your new file>)? Print the command before executing, and if it doesn't work, try to run the command in a terminal to make sure it works as expected.

Comment: os.execute() freezes the VLC player. I tested the os.rename command outside of vlc and it works fine. So the error must be in the permissions which VLC player gets from Windows.

Answer (score 0):

I might be wrong, but maybe the file you are trying to rename is already opened elsewhere or by VLC (you said you want to rename the "current file").

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Sadly the file is untouched and can be renamed without a problem in the editor.